# Passing variables from flask site to react component

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have a Flask (Python) project, and I needed to create dynamic and user-friendly content on a specific part of the website. So, I used REACT to create a component, which I then exported and inserted into my site by taking the generated JS and CSS files from the build process and pasting it on the flask page. The react component is render on a DIV element on the DOM of the Flask Page.

My question now is **how to pass environment variables (Flask rendered Variables) from the parent application (Flask) to this react JS file**. For example, I would like to pass the logged-in user's name or a token for making queries.

Thanks in advance

So Far I saw different types of integrations between Flask and React that uses JWT integration always managed from inside the react app. The problem there is that both components are isolated and different layers. I want to use this react component as it was a JS plug in.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to mention is that flask and react shares the same session information so for log-in purpose and requests, react took naturally the cookie that flask site generated. Are there other ways to pass information to the javascript file:

var _var1
var _var2

where react.build.js.file is the build of the react component.